# C functions pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

Since I don't know much(anything) , here probably everything's wrong, I'm just learning pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int,int);
void func(int*,int*);

int main()
{
    int i=2,j=5;
    void fun(i,j);
    printf("\n%d %d\n",i,j);
    void func(&i,&j);
    printf("\n%d %d\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int i, int j)
{
    i = i*i;
    j=j*j;
}

void func(int* i, int* j)
{
    *i = *i*(*i);
    *j = *j*(*j);
}
```

I want the output to be

> 2 5
>
> 4 25

func should permanently modify the values of i,j how do i do it
Please modify the program for me
Thanks

Comment: `void fun(i,j);` in your main should be just `fun(i,j);`. The same for your second function call. Edit: I get the output, which you want to have.

Comment: As an aside, forward-declaring `fun` and `func` and shuffling the definitions around does not gain you anything. Why do you do it?

Comment: what is fun function doing ?

Comment: Throw everything away and replace it with `printf ("2 5\n\n4 25\n");`.

Comment: @Jongware lol, I want the func function to point to i,j and hence modify their values permanently

Comment: -1 `here probably everything's wrong` can you elaborate it? It's pretty clear from your code that you have compilation error due to `void` keyword in `main` before `fun` and `func` function call. Just remove that both `void` and see the magic. Don't forgot to post actual error in question.

Comment: If you get a compiler error, it should be included in the post.

Comment: You could make `func` have `*i*=*i;` and `*j*=*j;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling functions,you mustn't specify the return type before it. So remove the `void`  before `fun` and `func` in the `main` function.